# What is null object pattern?

Tags: ruby

I think null object pattern is a way to reduce duplicated code for checking `nil` or doing something depending on the `nil` value. Is my thought wrong?

I refactored this code with null object: https://github.com/WithGJR/null. Please tell if I have something wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. There's the `nil` object in Ruby, but no equivalent to `null` as you might have in JavaScript. `nil` is more similar to `undefined`, as it's generally considered a non-value, even though it's an object which responds to methods.

Comment: By *Null Object* you're referring to an object that responds to any message by doing nothing and returning `nil`, right? That way you can say `might_be_a_null_object.any_method` without having to worry about explicit `nil` checks or `NoMethodError`s, right? A similar pattern would be saying `x.to_s` when `x` is supposed to be a string but might be `nil` and you want to treat `nil` the same way as an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

From your example, the so called `Null Object` concept is to not use Ruby `nil` in your code, because `nil` doesn't respond to the methods of `Subscription` class.

In the case of `nil`, you have to implement

```
def price
   # this will generate a NoMethodError: undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass
   subscription.price
end
```

as something like this:

```
def price
   subscription.try(:price) || 0
   # or if you don't use rails try method
   # subscription.nil? ? 0 : subscription.price
end
```

The introduction of `NullSubscription` makes sure that your `@subscription` object in `user.rb` always responds to methods `charge`, `has_mentoring?`, `price`, and those methods always return a proper value (no matter whether it's a real `Subscriptoin` instance or `NullSubscription` instance). So you can directly call `subscription.price` regardless.

(thanks for @FrederickCheung) If you search Rails source code for `module Null` and `class Null`, you could find some examples for this pattern.

In Rails app, people tend to use Rails `try` and `try!` methods to deal with nil object.

Comment: Taking advantage of `nil.to_s == ''`, `nil.to_i == 0`, `nil.to_a == []`, ... is also quite common. At least it is in my code.

Comment: At least one place it's used: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/null_relation.rb

Comment: @FrederickCheung, I didn't expect that :-). In fact, search `module Null` and `class Null` in rails code base returns plenty...